# How to create auto sequence with some criteria in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a range for example

Start from : SF1A1
End : SF23A8

Expected range like below

```
SF1A1
SF1A2
SF1A3
SF1A4
SF1A5
SF1A6
SF1A7
SF1A8

SF2A1
SF2A2
SF2A3
SF2A4
SF2A5
SF2A6
SF2A7
SF2A8
.
.
.
SF23A1
SF23A2
SF23A3
SF23A4
SF23A5
SF23A6
SF23A7
SF23A8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will do it:

```
="SF" & CEILING.MATH((ROW())/8) & "A" & (MOD(ROW()-1,8)+1)
```

put it anywhere in first row of a sheet and expand down.

**edit:** If you need it expanded automatically from and to a certain range, I think you'd have to use VBA. You can try this macro:

```vba
Sub sfa()
    Dim rng As String
    rng = InputBox("please enter range, example:" & vbCrLf & "SF5A2-SF7A7")
    Dim sfStart As Long, aStart As Long, sfEnd As Long, aEnd As Long
    
    On Error GoTo inputErrorHandling
        sfStart = Mid(Split(rng, "-")(0), 3, Len(Split(rng, "-")(0)) - 4)
        aStart = Right(Split(rng, "-")(0), 1)
        sfEnd = Mid(Split(rng, "-")(1), 3, Len(Split(rng, "-")(1)) - 4)
        aEnd = Right(Split(rng, "-")(1), 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
    Dim startVal As Long, endVal As Long
    startVal = (sfStart - 1) * 8 + aStart
    endVal = (sfEnd - 1) * 8 + aEnd
    
    If endVal - startVal > 1000 Then
        If MsgBox("WARNING, the range you are trying to create is " & (endVal - startVal) & " rows long. Do you want to proceed?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    For i = startVal To endVal
        Dim x As String
        Cells(Selection.Row + i - startVal, Selection.Column) = "SF" & WorksheetFunction.Ceiling_Math(i / 8) & "A" & (((i - 1) Mod 8) + 1)
    Next i
    Exit Sub
inputErrorHandling:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox ("invalid input")
End Sub
```

How to use: Select the cell where you want the series to start and run the macro. It will ask for a range, you can use your example but separate start and end of the sequence with a hyphen (ie. SF1A1-SF23A8)

Comment: awesome. thank you so much

Comment: @Liamneesan no problem. I also added another solution if you actually want to specify a start and end point and have the series be independent of rows. The answer is updated.